# PYGAME: nameError global name font is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

so I'm making this simple game in Pygame but when I try to show the death end text on screen i get the error message nameError: global name font is not defined. Please help as i cant see anyone else reporting this on the internet.
The error appears on line 57.
Heres the code:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.font.init()
x = pygame.init()
FPS = 15

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
magenta = (255,0,255)

screenWidth = 600
screenHeight = 600

userX = 350
userY = 250

carX = 250
carY = -20

car2X = 300
car2Y = -80

car3X = 350
car3Y = -160

busX = 300
busY = -280

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Highway")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

block_size = 10

gameOver = False
gameExit = False

def _cars_():
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, ((carX, carY), (10,20))) #car
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, ((car2X, car2Y), (10,20))) #car
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, yellow, ((car3X, car3Y), (10,20))) #car

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, ((busX, busY), (10, 40))) #bus

def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2])


while not gameExit:

    message_to_screen("CRASH! Try again? [Y/N]", magenta)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_y:
                gameOver = False

    while not gameOver:
        gameDisplay.fill(green)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, ((225,0),(150,600)))
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, ((userX, userY), (10,20)))
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, ((275,0), (2.5,600)))
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, ((325,0), (2.5,600)))
        _cars_()



        pygame.display.update()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    userX -= 50

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    userX += 50

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    userY -= 20

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    userY += 20

        carY += 10
        car2Y += 10
        car3Y += 10
        busY += 10


        #car move
        if carY > 600 and carX == 250:
            carY = -20
            carX = 350
        if carY > 600 and carX == 350:
            carY = -20
            carX = 300
        if carY > 600 and carX == 300:
            carY = -20
            carX = 250
        #car2 move
        if car2Y > 600 and car2X == 250:
            car2Y = -10
            car2X = 350
        if car2Y > 600 and car2X == 350:
            car2Y = -20
            car2X = 300
        if car2Y > 600 and car2X == 300:
            car2Y = -20
            car2X = 250

            #car3 move
        if car3Y > 600 and car3X == 350:
            car3Y = -30
            car3X = 300
        if car3Y > 600 and car3X == 300:
            car3Y = -30
            car3X = 250
        if car3Y > 600 and car3X == 250:
            car3Y = -30
            car3X = 350
            #bus move
        if busY > 600 and busX == 300:
            busY = -40
            busX = 350
        if busY > 600 and busX == 350:
            busY = -40
            busX = 250
        if busY > 600 and busX == 250:
            busY = -40
            busX = 300

        if userX == carX and userY == carY:
            gameExit = True
        if userX == car2X and userY == car2Y:
            gameOver = True
        if userX == car3X and userY == car3Y:
            gameOver = True
        if userX == busX and userY == busY:
            gameOver = True

        clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You're never defining a variable called `font`

Answer (score -1):

You are referring to a global variable `font`; I suspect you mean to refer to `pygame.font` instead.

```
def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2])
```

would become:

```
def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = pygame.font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, I followed what you said and i got another error, attributeError: 'module' object has no attribute render. Sorry if Im nagging you but this is my first game written by myself and I tend to lose motivation quite quickly if things just dont work, anyways, thank you.

Comment: @JakeTraynor Can you link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: I'm not following a tutorial :/

Comment: @JakeTraynor I'm never used PyGame so I can't give you a definitive answer. It looks like there is no `render` function in the `pygame.font` module though - `render` is a method on `pygame.font.Font` objects ([see here in the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render)). Sorry I can't help more!

Comment: Its my first game that I'm working on that's not from a tutorial.

Comment: I fixed it haha silly mistake from me I forgot to define font! sorry for wasting your time :/

Comment: Pygame in module 'pygame.font' has no attribute 'render'